# SimpleOnGestureListener: onDoubleTap disabled when onSingleTapConfirmed is implemented

Tags: android, event-handling, gesturedetector

I am implementing a GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.

I first implemented the onDoubleTap() method and had it working fine.  I then implemented the onSingleTapConfirmed() method.  I find that when this method exists in my listener, the onDoubleTap method is greyed out indicating it is never called.  Sure enough, if I run the app, the double tap no longer is called.  This happens even if the onSingleTapConfirmed() just returns false.

I don't see any logical reason why the listener and respond to both single and double taps.   Anyone know why this would be?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, but show your code, for me both methods works.

Also you can try to implement `onDoubleTapEvent()` method (not only `onDoubleTap()`, if it makes any change for you.

Maybe also setting listener `gestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener(listener)` would help, but I'm not using it.